# Object create in C++

Tags: c++, object

I have a little question about a code example in C++.

```
vector<Cat> v;
Cat c;
v.push_back(c);
Cat d = v[0];
```

In this piece of code, how many objects are created?

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: Are you interested in the total number of objects, or just the number of `Cat` objects? For example, do you want to count `v` as an object, or just the `Cat` objects *in* `v`?

Comment: It is impossible to say.  What does the default constructor of `Cat` do?  Does it construct other objects?  Can it throw an exception?  Can it call `std::exit()`?  What about the `Cat` copy constructor?  What does it do?  What about the implementation of `std::vector` being used?  Is it possible that any of the allocations it attempts will fail?  Do subobjects need to be counted as well?

Comment: How many do you think are created and why?

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan no this is a part of lecture slide, just want to make sure I got the right idea. thank you!

Comment: @AdrianCornish I think there are two objects are created. one is c and one is d...

Comment: Since you're learning this in class, this counts as homework--we'll help you reach the answer, but SO doesn't like giving students the answers outright. Hope that makes sense. :)

Comment: @AllanJiang What about 'v' and alsso the push back creates an object. Assuming you are only talking about std::vector and Cat objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least three:

```
vector<Cat> v;
Cat c;  // default construction
v.push_back(c); // copy construction of v[0] from c
Cat d = v[0];  // copy construction of d from v[0]
```

Edit: Note that I only count `Cat` objects here, because it doesn't make sense to ask how many objects **in total** are created, because that would be implementation specific (how is `std::vector` implemented? What does `Cat` do? ...)

Answer (score 1):

Add some logging to the constructor of Cat and test it yourself:

```
class Cat
{
  Cat() 
  {
    std::cout<<"Constructing a Cat"<<std::endl;
  }
  Cat( const Cat & cat )
  {
    std::cout<<"Copy Constructing a Cat"<<std::endl;
  }
};
```

Here's what I get: http://codepad.org/Pzs9kOlH

Note that under certain conditions the compiler is free to remove chunks of code that do nothing. So some copies may get removed. With a hypothetical very agressive compiler it might notice that nothing is done by your code and completely strip out any such constructions altogether. Since my constructors now change the output the compiler is less free to remove calls to them.